# Composition of holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $g:\mathbb C^m\longrightarrow \mathbb C$ is holomorphic and that $F:\mathbb C^n\longrightarrow \mathbb C^m$ is a continuous function. If $g\circ F$ is holomorphic, then  is it true that also $F$ is holomorphic?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. Let $g = 0$ and $F$ any continuous, but non-holomorphic function. But: If $g \circ F$ is holomorphic for *any* holomorphic $g$, then $F$ is also holomorphic.

Comment: in this case $g\circ F$ is the zero function which is holomorphic.

Comment: Correct. But we cannot conclude anything for $F$.

Comment: Ah ok it is clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As martini said, this isn't true as stated. One needs $g$ to be nonconstant, at the very least. If $n=m=1$, then $g$ being nonconstant is enough:

**Claim**. If

- $g:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ is holomorphic and nonconstant
- $F:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ is continuous
- $g\circ F$ is holomorphic

then $F$ is holomorphic.

*Proof*. If $F$ is constant, we are done. Otherwise, one can check that $h:=g\circ F$ is nonconstant. Therefore, the set of its critical points is discrete. If $z$ is not a critical point of $h$, then $h$ is injective in a neighborhood of $z$. Hence, $g$  is injective near $F(z)$, which implies it has a holomorphic inverse $g^{-1}$. Writing $F=g^{-1}\circ h$, we conclude that $F$ is holomorphic near $z$. Finally, a continuous function that is holomorphic outside of a discrete set is holomorphic. $\quad \Box$

The situation in higher dimensions is rather different, and I do not know what additional assumptions will be needed to conclude that $F$ is holomorphic.